# Use of develop+on

Tags: grammaticality

Can one use 'develop on'?

I've never heard of this use before, but it is in a sentence found in an education journal, so perhaps acceptable?

> e.g. **Developing on** these critical reviews...

Comment: Is it used in the sense of _develop on the basis of…_?

Comment: no, if I understand your example correctly. It seems to be used in the sense of building on. Like _Building on these reviews..._